# Why is infinite loop not incrementing integer?

Tags: loops, go, concurrency

This prints 0.

But when I add empty fmt.Println() in for loop its prints non zero value.
Any ideas why?

```sh
GOMAXPROCS=1 ./foo
0
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var i uint64
    t := time.AfterFunc(time.Second*1, func() {
        log.Println(i)
        os.Exit(0)
    })
    defer t.Stop()

    for {
        i++
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a data race: you access the same variable from multiple goroutines without synchronization. The results are undefined. Use proper synchronization.

Comment: @icza why? The code is not visibly made concurrent using multiple goroutines. It's not doing `for { go i++ }`. This should be a single-routine?

Comment: You have the main goroutine and the one that will call / execute the function passed to `time.AfterFunc()`.

Comment: @icza In this case, is the log statement not evaluated after 1 second?

Comment: @AhmetB-Google When you have data race, the results are undefined.

Comment: You cannot argue about a racy program. The only thing you can say about a racy program is: It is just wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a data race: you access the same variable from multiple goroutines without synchronization. The results are undefined. Use proper synchronization.

It's true that you don't launch goroutines in your code, but quoting from [`time.AfterFunc()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#AfterFunc):

> AfterFunc waits for the duration to elapse and then **calls f in its own goroutine**.

So you have the `main` goroutine incrementing (writing) the variable `i`, and you'll have another goroutine executing the function you pass to `time.AfterFunc()` which will read `i`.

Example to use synchronization:

```
var (
    mu sync.Mutex
    i  uint64
)
t := time.AfterFunc(time.Second*1, func() {
    mu.Lock()
    log.Println(i)
    mu.Unlock()
    os.Exit(0)
})
defer t.Stop()

for {
    mu.Lock()
    i++
    mu.Unlock()
}
```

Comment: I think the odd part is that even after 1 second, it reads a zero value despite reading it 1 second later. Does the `for {}` not make any progress in 1 second?

Comment: Again: with data race, the results are undefined. There's no point reasoning about what and why happens. Only when you have no data race.